# How to enable USBIP on Rocky Linux

Tags: rhel, usb

I want to enable usbip server on rocky linux and tried to run this command
`sudo modprobe usbip`
and
`sudo modprobe usbip-host`
and i got the same error:

`modprobe: FATAL: Module usbip not found in directory /lib/modules/4.18.0-425.19.2.el8_7.x86_64`

and

`modprobe: FATAL: Module usbip-host not found in directory /lib/modules/4.18.0-425.19.2.el8_7.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

You could install `elrepo`, that one contains the `kmod-usbip` package as well as newer kernels if you like...

see https://elrepo.org/